# Submit on an ASP.NET MVC form?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way I can get the returned value from an action using .submit event listener in jQuery?
I have a problem which is when the action is completed it returns a JSON file and my browser navigates to an empty page and just display the JSON returned. I don't want that to happen, I want to be able to read the JSON result and based on it decide what to do.

Here's my POC:
View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitTest", "DMS", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { id = "formId" }))
        {
            <input type="submit" value="Sumbit" />
        }
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult SubmitTest()
        {
            return Json("Done");
        }
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("formId").submit(function () {
            alert("Submitted");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add `event.preventDefault` or `return false` to prevent the default event from occurring . so it won't navigate to an empty page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("formId").submit(function () {
            alert("Submitted");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

**EDIT:**
if you want to get the response you need to make an ajax request and get the form data from the fields. you can't get the response with `submit` function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("formId").submit(function () {
            /// make an AJAX request
             $.post(
 $(this).attr('action'), //// action url
 $(this).serialize(), //// serialize form fields
function(json) {
        alert(json);/// json response
    }, 'json');

            return false; /// prevent navigation
        });
    });
```

Comment: Won't this prevent submitting the form to the server?

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni no it won't . it submits the form but prevents navigation

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AJAX` form instead of the `HTML` form, this way you can check the response after it is submitted and do whatever you need using the `OnSuccess` handler.

For detailed info refer to this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/0c1bb2/ajax-beginform-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)